# Ios Native Geofencing doubts

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation

I have a couple of doubts about the Ios native geofencing features.

1. The documentation describes that there's a maximun number of regions to add y the number is 20. Is possible to change dinamically the regions according (for example) to the city where the device is? (To increase the number of regions that can be monitoring)
2. Is possible to get the regions to monitoring from a config file at mobile app start? (In order of configurate the regions file and later the device get the regions from there)
3. Other doubt that I have is about something that I read: "The regions is shared by all apps, and older fences will get purged to make room for newer fences". This means that if I have a region 1 and a region 2 and a device1 and device2, if the device1 monitoring for the region1, the device2 could not monitor region1?
4. Can a device monitors for more than one region?

Thanks a lot who can help me with this doubts!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An application can monitor no more than twenty regions or geofences.  You can update the regions if user has moved far enough.
2. Yes.
3. No, regions are not shared in any way across apps.
4. Yes.